# DOM breaks on loading lots of data in dialogue popup window in Excel?

Tags: excel, dom, office365, office-js

I am facing issue with table rendering. The table contains 3 columns with auto-complete dropdown, in which each dropdown contains more than 50 data. Hence if response gets more than 100 rows dom just crashes.

Is there any optimal way to render data in the dropdowns to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

for each keyboard enter one can hit the server, but I don't think that's a good way.